# How to stop jquery animation smoothly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have a button, on clicking upon which the jquery animation is stopped. I want to not stop the animation instantly, but instead continue the animation for a short time after clicking the button. Here's what I have tried:

```js
//autoscroll module starts  
! function() {
  var now_scrollable;
  var max_scrollable = $(".container").prop("scrollWidth") - $(".container").outerWidth();
  var one_scroll = 1500 / max_scrollable;

  $("#start").click(
    function() {
      now_scrollable = max_scrollable - $(".container").scrollLeft();
      $(".container").stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: max_scrollable
      }, one_scroll * now_scrollable);
    });

  $("#stop").click(
    function() {
      $(".container").stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $(".container").scrollLeft() + 20
      }, 300);
    });

  $("#reset").click(function() {
    $(".container").scrollLeft(0);
  });
}();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.scroll {
  width: 1400px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll"></div>
</div>

<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

As you can see when press `stop` the scrolling first instantly reaches 0 speed then it start scrolls next 20 pixel. I want a smooth change of speed when stop is clicked.

1. How do I acheive a smooth scrolling when stop is pressed. Currently there appears a break then restart effect.
2. Using jquery `stop` removes all the animations running on the element. How to remove only namespaced animations using? Should I use `queue` and `dequeue`?

Cheers : )

Comment: I gave it a shot, but was not able to figure out a simple way of doing this. However, another person asked a similar question. This might be able to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442604/jquery-animation-stop-triggering-easeout

Comment: @GeneParcellano Thanks. I don't know so much jquery yest but I will try to make use of that code as it is.